# Create azure logic app from azure function

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am wondering if there is a way to create an Azure logic app (given we have the definition of the logic app as a JSON file) from an Azure function.

To be more clear, I have done this in the past with AWS Lambda and State Machine ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_CreateStateMachine.html)). As you can see given the definition of statemachine we can call `CreateStateMachine` in a Lambda function with additional required fields and create a state machine.

Knowing the concept of Azure Logic App is almost similar to AWS Statemachine and Azure function to AWS Lambda, I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this. If you know it please guide me to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create or perform any other Workflow Operations on Azure Logic Apps using the REST APIs.

You need to send a `PUT` request to the below URL with your logicapp definition.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}?api-version=2016-06-01
```

Remember you will also need a `bearer_token` to [Authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) your request.

Create Or Update Logic App(Workflow) -> [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows/createorupdate)

Possible workflow operations - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows)

#### To get Bearer Token use the below snippet

```
string authority = $"https://login.windows.net/{request.TenantId}";

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var credential = new ClientCredential(request.ClientId, request.ClientSecret);
var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Resource, credential).Result;
var accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
```